# How do we size a vertical line to match a frame size

Tags: html, css

How do I size a vertical line using css?
I need my vertical line to match the size of the frame. The vertical line must be in the center and must divide the frame into two equal sizes. Or is there any other way to output a vertical line? 
Below is my html and css code:

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
}

.card {
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 20%;
  padding-right: 20%;
  background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
}

#myPug {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.fact {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.factList {
  font-family: cursive;
  font-size: 25px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.listContent {
  text-align: left;
}

.info {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.infoBox {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(55, 150, 210);
  border-radius: 10%;
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-right: 30%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.topic {
  text-align: left;
}

.topicDescription {
  text-align: right;
}

.prop {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.vl {
  align-self: center;
  border-left: solid;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  color: black;
  height: 200px;
}

.length {
  width: 1;
  size: 500;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="card">
  <img id="myPug" src="images/burfi.jpg" alt="A cute pug's pic">
  <div class="infoBox">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <p class="info prop">Name:</p>
        <p class="info prop">Age: </p>
        <p class="info prop">Breed: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="vl">&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <p class="info def"><em> BURFI</em></p>
        <p class="info def"><em> 2 Yrs</em></p>
        <p class="info def"><em> Pug</em></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Below is a snapshot of my webpage:

[image: AnimalCard snapshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.infoBox` has a `padding-top: 20px` that is causing the space. If you want some padding, do it with the **inner** columns.

A flexbox solution without Bootstrap

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 0 50px;
}

.box img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.box ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.box .vl {
  width: 3px;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
}

.box .info {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 3px solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.box .info>div:nth-child(1),
.box .info>div:nth-child(3) {
  padding: 0 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="">
  <div class="info">
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>List 1</li>
        <li>List 2</li>
        <li>List 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="vl"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>List 1</li>
        <li>List 2</li>
        <li>List 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Sun. How do I set the height of the line to the height of the box frame?

Comment: The vertical line has a height of `200px`. Therefore give the other columns the height of `200px` and each `<p>` inside of it a height `33.333%`.

Comment: Another solution with flexbox. See the edited answer!